# Https Web API from console app or android app

Tags: c#

I have an Https Web API hosted in Azure.
Now if I am making a call from console application, will the POST/GET data be passed in encrypted form or will I need to do anything in the console app?>
the reason I am asking is that if I use Fiddler, can see the data in clear text. Of course decrypt HTTPS traffic is checked

Similarly  if the Web api is consumed from Android mobile app, does the app need to do anything to ensure that the traffic cannot be sniffed?

I am new to Https and security. Any help or pointer will be of immense help

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making your Web API **only** accessible by HTTPS. And then, make sure that yoru Android app uses HTTPS. Also, ensure that if your Android app is presented with an invalid certificate that it will stop running and not send any data.

HTTPS should basically handle everything from a sniffing/MITM point of view. However, you must still have a secure authentication mechanism and such as well.

Comment: WebAPI calls are authenticated. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by Android uses https?

Comment: Also if i consume an webapi through console app, will the calls be secure?
How is that fiddler is able to decrypt the https traffic? is it because i am not using any cert in the console app?

Comment: If you use HTTPS (HTTP with SSL) to connect to your Web API from your Android app, it's safe and people won't be able to sniff what you send over the wire

Comment: Fiddler decrypts HTTPS traffic by installing it's own certificate(that is not trusted). In a production scenario, that would never happen

Comment: can you please elaborate on this(fiddler install its own cert)? When Web API IIS server is configured with a cert and a call is made from console app what cert is used to encrypt the traffic?(without fiddler in picture)

And how does this change when we use fiddler?